# How to change sender email Id using hook_mail_alter

Tags: 8, hooks, emails

How to change the sender email id for some emails, using hook_mail_alter. The default SMTP configured email ID is 'test@myfirstdomain.com'

The subject gets altered correctly using the hook_mail_alter, however, the email which I receive is still from the default configured email 'test@myfirstdomain.com'.

```
function test_mail_alter(&$message) {
 switch ($message['key']) {
  case 'activation':
    
    $from = "test@myseconddomain.com" ;
    $message['from'] = $from;
    $message['headers']['From'] = $from;
    $message['headers']['Sender'] = $from;
    $message['headers']['Return-Path'] = $from;
    $message['subject'] = 123;
    break;
}
```

}

Answer (score -4):

According to the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/8.7.x):

```
/**
 * Alter an email message created with MailManagerInterface->mail().
 *
 * Hook hook_mail_alter() allows modification of email messages created and sent
 * with MailManagerInterface->mail(). Usage examples include adding and/or
 * changing message text, message fields, and message headers.
 *
 * Email messages sent using functions other than MailManagerInterface->mail()
 * will not invoke hook_mail_alter(). For example, a contributed module directly
 * calling the MailInterface->mail() or PHP mail() function will not invoke
 * this hook. All core modules use MailManagerInterface->mail() for messaging,
 * it is best practice but not mandatory in contributed modules.
...
```

Can we check if the mail is sent `MailManagerInterface->mail()` like this and not any other way.

Comment: The subject gets altered and that confirms the hook is invoked